# How to deploy maven artifacts depending on their profile?

Tags: maven

I am using a public maven repository on Github to deploy new versions of my open source java project. The project can be built in two different versions which are defined by profile configurations in the pom.xml
When I deploy my artifact the default build will be uploaded into the repository.
Is it possible to deploy different maven builds depending on different profiles with the same maven version number? Or is there a concept or best practice of how to use different version numbers of a maven artifact depending on the selected profile?

Comment: "different version numbers of a maven artifact depending on the selected profile?". This doesn't make sense. This goes against the concept of version. It sounds like you want to deploy multiple artifacts with a classifier instead. With the same version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you're asking, but associating a classifier with your artifacts might be what you're looking for.  For instance, if you needed a 'prod' and 'stage' artifact with different profiles, you would do something like this:

```
<profiles>
   <profile>
     <id>stage</id>
     <build>
       <plugins>
         .
         .
         <plugin>
           <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
           <executions>
             <execution>
               <phase>package</phase>
               <goals>
                 <goal>jar</goal>
               </goals>
               <configuration>
                 <classifier>stage</classifier>
               </configuration>
             </execution>
           </executions>
         </plugin>
       </plugins>
     </build>
   </profile>
```

Running your 'stage' profile would give you a '-stage' artifact.  Although, I would argue that there are usually better ways to do this, it's not uncommon to use profiles to [build for different environments](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html).  Is this what you're trying to do?

Comment: yes this what I am looking for. I build War-Templates with a rest service. Depending on the target platform (Glassfish, Wildfly) I need to configure different JAX-RS impl (jersey,RestEasy). This is why I want to provide different artifacts in one release

Comment: Gotcha.  So if you're building .wars, why not package your application source into a .jar and have a different modules for each target platform with their own respective descriptors/resources?  It would be a more maven-y way of doing it (1 artifact per module) and you wouldn't have a massive pom.xml in a single module.

Comment: But the difference for JAX-RS configuration is in the web.xml file itself. I think there is no other way as to build different war modules for each platform?

Comment: You're right in that web.xml differences mandate that you build different artifacts.  I was just suggesting the alternative of compiling your shared code as a .jar, and then having a .war module for each unique web.xml you have.  That way you wouldn't have to try to match a bunch of web.xml resources to profiles within a single project.  At the end of the day your artifacts should function the same, just a different way to get there.